# Adding Annotations to coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to place annotations in the bottom left corner of a plot with polar coordinates.

Is there a way of doing this by using coordinates that are not part of the circular coordinate system (as shown, which doesn't allow me to place them far out) but a normal x and y system?

I don't need the axes to show but have left them in to help show what's going on.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())
ggplot(iris2) +      
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = id, xend = id, 
                   y = 10, 
                   yend = 10 + Sepal.Length),
               size = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  annotate(geom="text", x = 90, y = 10, label="Annotation",
           color="Red") +
  annotate(geom="text", x = 90, y = 15, label="Annotation",
           color="Blue")
```

[image]

Comment: See [cowplot](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/drawing_with_on_plots.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `cowplot` package to make the desired plot. You can make two `text_grob` that will be the text labels and then add them on the lower and left side of the plot you already have (appears as p1 in the following code).

```
library(cowplot)

#X axis text
x <- textGrob(label = "X text",
              gp=gpar(fontsize=12,
                      fontface = "bold"),
              hjust = 0.1)
#Y axis text
y <- textGrob(label = "Y text",
              #rotate it 90 degrees
              rot = 90,
              gp=gpar(fontsize=12,
                      fontface = "bold"))

#Get X axis text and p1 together in a 2 row array
p2<-plot_grid(p1,x, 
              nrow = 2,
              rel_widths = c(4,1),
              rel_heights = c(20,1))

#Get Y axis text and p2 together in 2 column array
p3<-plot_grid(y,p2, 
              ncol = 2,
              rel_widths = c(1,20),
              rel_heights = c(1,4))
p3
```

[image: Final plot]

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Aexman's helpful comment to try [cowplot](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/drawing_with_on_plots.html), I did and came up with the following.  It means you can add two layers together, the second with an independent coordinate system.

Coordinates are between 0 and 1 for both axes, relative the bottom left corner.  Absolute positioning is also available.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

iris2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

g <- ggplot(iris2) +      
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = id, xend = id, 
                   y = 10, 
                   yend = 10 + Sepal.Length),
               size = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE)

ggdraw(g) +
  draw_label("Annotation", x = 0.05, y = 0.05, hjust = 0, vjust = 0,
             fontfamily = "", fontface = "plain", color = "black", size = 14,
             colour = "Red")
```